# New line disappears after Invoke

Tags: c#, newline, invoke

I've got a silly minor problem here. For context, using C#, I'm communicating between some sockets and I want to display output from worker threads.

I have these lines to display output:

```
txtOutput.AppendText("Client - Sending the following message: " + Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes) + Environment.NewLine);

txtOutput.Invoke(new Action(() =>  txtOutput.AppendText("Client - Server returned a message: " + str + Environment.NewLine)));
```

The first line is added from the program's main thread, the second from a worker thread.

The first line always shows up fine, then the second one does too. But when I do the sequence again, first line B is pasted onto the second line A, with second line B looking correct again. So obviously the second line's NewLine is disappearing, but I don't really understand why or how to fix this.

Comment: Try make a string variable first and then append the string, still the same problem?

Comment: Sadly, that makes no difference!

Comment: I am testing right now, And it works without the bytes. So something with the encoding of "bytes" mess this upp..

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this. I think your problem is the Encoding.

When you send a message:

```
string message = input(textbox ex);
UTF8Encoding utf8 = new UTF8Encoding();
byte[] encodedbytes = utf8.GetBytes(message);
```

And keep your code as it is at receive.

I tested this with the following:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    private Thread thread;
    private byte[] encodedBytes2;
    private byte[] encodedBytes;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        UTF8Encoding utf8 = new UTF8Encoding();
        string unicodeString = "Quick brown fox";
        encodedBytes = utf8.GetBytes(unicodeString);

        encodedBytes2 = new byte[20];
        encodedBytes2[0] = (byte)'r';
        encodedBytes2[1] = (byte)'e';


        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            textBox1.AppendText("ENCODED " + Encoding.ASCII.GetString(encodedBytes) + Environment.NewLine);

        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            textBox1.AppendText(" NOT ENCODED " + Encoding.ASCII.GetString(encodedBytes2) + Environment.NewLine);

        thread = new Thread(ThreadWork);
        thread.IsBackground = true;
        thread.Start();
    }

    private void ThreadWork()
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            textBox1.Invoke(new Action(() => textBox1.AppendText("THREAD ENCODED " + Encoding.ASCII.GetString(encodedBytes) + Environment.NewLine)));

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            textBox1.Invoke(new Action(() => textBox1.AppendText("THREAD NOT ENCODED " + Encoding.ASCII.GetString(encodedBytes2) + Environment.NewLine)));
    }
}
```

And the output turned out this in a multiline textbox:

ENCODED Quick brown fox
ENCODED Quick brown fox
ENCODED Quick brown fox
ENCODED Quick brown fox
ENCODED Quick brown fox
 NOT ENCODED re NOT ENCODED re NOT ENCODED re NOT ENCODED re NOT ENCODED reTHREAD ENCODED Quick brown fox
THREAD ENCODED Quick brown fox
THREAD ENCODED Quick brown fox
THREAD ENCODED Quick brown fox
THREAD ENCODED Quick brown fox
THREAD NOT ENCODED reTHREAD NOT ENCODED reTHREAD NOT ENCODED reTHREAD NOT ENCODED reTHREAD NOT ENCODED re